# Creating a bipolar chart using Javascript & PHP

Tags: javascript, php, variables, charts

I'm new to PHP & Javascript hence probably a lot of rookie errors - I am trying to pass in 4 php variables such as 'mildly active' to Javascript with assigned values and then plot them on the Javascript chart. Any advice as to where I am going wrong? The labels of the chart will never move such as Active & Reflective as they are opposites and their value is held in dimension1. What would be the most effective way of passing the values to the chart? Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

    $dbQuery = $db->prepare("select dimension1, dimension2, dimension3, dimension4 FROM indexLearningStyle WHERE studentNumber = '".$currentUser."'");
    $dbQuery-> execute();

    while ($dbRow = $dbQuery->fetch (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $dimension1 = $dbRow["dimension1"];
    $dimension2 = $dbRow["dimension2"];
    $dimension3 = $dbRow["dimension3"];
    $dimension4 = $dbRow["dimension4"]; 

    }

    $stronglyActive = 0;
    $moderatelyActive = 0.16;
    $mildlyActive = 0.32;

    $stronglyReflective = 1.0;
    $moderatelyReflective = 0.84;
    $mildlyReflective = 0.68;

    $stronglySensing = 0;
    $moderatelySensing = 0.16;
    $mildlySensing = 0.32; 

    $stronglyIntuitive = 1.0;
    $moderatelyIntuitive = 0.84;
    $mildlyIntuitive = 0.68;

    $stronglyVisual = 0;
    $moderatelyVisual = 0.16;
    $mildlyVisual = 0.32;

    $stronglyVerbal = 1.0;
    $moderatelyVerbal = 0.84;
    $mildlyVerbal = 0.68;

    $stronglySequential = 0;
    $moderatelySequential = 0.16;
    $mildlySequential = 0.32;

    $stronglyGlobal = 1.0;
    $moderatelyGlobal = 0.84;
    $mildlyGlobal = 0.68;



  ?>
  </body>

  <body class="">

  <br><br>
        <div id="studentILS">
        </div>
  </div>
  <br><br><br>


<!-- scripts -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="cssBipolarChart.js"></script>

<script>

    var dimension1 = <?php $dimension1 ?>;
    var dimension2 = <?php $dimension2 ?>;
    var dimension3 = <?php $dimension3 ?>;
    var dimension4 = <?php $dimension4 ?>;

    var stronglyActive = <?php $stronglyActive ?>;
    var moderatelyActive = <?php $moderatelyActive ?>;
    var mildlyActive = <?php $mildlyActive ?>;

    var stronglyReflective = <?php $stronglyReflective ?>;
    var moderatelyReflective = <?php $moderatelyReflective ?>;
    var mildlyReflective = <?php $mildlyReflective ?>;

    var stronglySensing = <?php $stronglySensing ?>;
    var moderatelySensing = <?php $moderatelySensing ?>;
    var mildlySensing = <?php $mildlySensing ?>;

    var stronglyIntuitive = <?php $stronglyIntuitive ?>;
    var moderatelyIntuitive = <?php $moderatelyIntuitive ?>;
    var mildlyIntuitive = <?php $mildlyIntuitive ?>;

    var stronglyVisual = <?php $stronglyVisual ?>;
    var moderatelyVisual = <?php $moderatelyVisual ?>;
    var mildlyVisual = <?php $mildlyVisual ?>;

    var stronglyVerbal = <?php $stronglyVerbal ?>;
    var moderatelyVerbal = <?php $moderatelyVerbal ?>;
    var mildlyVerbal = <?php $mildlyVerbal ?>;

    var stronglySequential = <?php $stronglySequential ?>;
    var moderatelySequential = <?php $moderatelySequential ?>;
    var mildlySequential = <?php $mildlySequential ?>;

    var stronglyGlobal = <?php $stronglyGlobal ?>;
    var moderatelyGlobal = <?php $moderatelyGlobal ?>;
    var mildlyGlobal = <?php $mildlyGlobal ?>;



    var studentResults = [
        ["Active", "Reflective", 0],
        ["Sensing", "Intuitive", 0.16],
        ["Visual", "Verbal", 0.32],
        ["Sequential", "Global", 0.68],
        ["Sequential", "Global", 0.84],
        ["Sequential", "Global", 1.0]
    ]

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#studentILS").drawCSSBipolarChart({
            data: studentResults,
            bipolar: true
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: You got a whole lot of vars which are not being used  its confusing as to what vars you want in the chart, why not define the variables to the studentResults array or use the ones set globally?

Comment: Also your `</body>` ends before it starts `<body>` :/

Answer (score 0):

As @Lawrence mentioned you should use array & correct  tag.

Here is the simple code you should try:

```
<?php
    //Fetch following values and assign to array
    $stronglyGlobal = 1.0;
    $moderatelyGlobal = 0.84;
    $mildlyGlobal = 0.68;
?>
<!-- Correct opening/closing body-->
<div id="studentILS"></div>
<!-- scripts -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="cssBipolarChart.js"></script>

<script>
    //Loop through PHP array & print var in JavaScript
    var stronglyGlobal = <?php echo $stronglyGlobal ?>; //Notice echo over here
    var moderatelyGlobal = <?php echo $moderatelyGlobal ?>;
    var mildlyGlobal = <?php echo $mildlyGlobal ?>;

    var studentResults = [
        ["Sequential", "Global", mildlyGlobal], //Updated values assigned
        ["Sequential", "Global", stronglyGlobal],
        ["Sequential", "Global", moderatelyGlobal]
    ]

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#studentILS").drawCSSBipolarChart({
            data: studentResults,
            bipolar: true
        })
    })
</script>
```

Hope this answer will give you hint.